# Duplicate content in ASP.NET MVC because of Query String

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, seo

I can add any additional parameters to every ASP.NET MVC Method and MVC just ignore this parameters. The problem is that Google mark such pages as duplicate content. For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
```

if I add link this this page like http://example.com/?abc=123 it is a duplicate content for Google. Is there any way to avoid this with ASP.NET MVC and allow only existing parameters?

Comment: Is it possible for you to change your routes to http://www.example.com/123 ?

Comment: This parameter is only for example. My competition creates a lot of links like ?a1=1, ?a2=1, ?a3=1 and so on. Google lower my rank because of this duplicate pages. I can manually exclude links in Google Webmaster Tools, but with thousands of such links it is very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use the Request object to cycle through the query string and throw an error if there is something there that you don't want like so:

```
foreach (string a in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
{
    // throw error if there is a key here we don't want
}
```

However, that this happens is really just a fact of the web and I don't think you should worry about it. If you are concerned about it then just don't create links to pages on your site with invalid parameters.